# 3ds Max textures/custom materials

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I read in the `Viewer Release Notes: v4.0.1` that `Protein Materials tiling patterns` (Revit 2019) are now supported. This is great! However, as a 3ds Max user I am curious whether there's any plans to support `bitmap-textures` or `custom materials` coming from 3ds Max? That would really generate new possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the older version, but as you can see from the following screenshot on a scene created by one of colleagues: 
[image]

There should not be problems on converting the max file with textures, as long as you follow the following steps:

1. Archive the max file along with its textures and upload it to a bucket.
   For example (with Python):

```python
filename = 'max_archive.zip'
bucket_name = bucketKey

url = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com"
my_object_endpoint = "/oss/v2/buckets/" + bucket_name + "/objects/" + filename
header = {
           "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
           "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
           "Content-Length": str(os.path.getsize(filename)),
         }    
with open(filename, 'rb') as object_to_upload:
        response_upload = requests.put(url + my_object_endpoint, headers=header, data=object_to_upload)
```

2. Send a translation job specifying that it is an archive and the root of this archive is your max file. 
   For example (with Python):

```python
job_endpoint = '/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job'
header = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

payload = json.dumps({
    "input" : {
        "urn": '"' + encoded_urn + '"',
        "rootFilename": "physical_material.max",
        "compressedUrn": True
    },
    "output": {
        "formats": [
            {
                "type": "svf",
                "views": [
                    "2d",
                    "3d"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
})

response = requests.post(url+job_endpoint, headers=header, data=payload)
```

The key point here is the ***input*** part of the payload, where you have to specify the *rootFilename* and set the *compression* as *true*.

In my case I got the result as in the above presented screenshot.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I am using Postman for my translations (https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/my-postman-collectio). I'll try to specify the important settings in there and do some testing.