# 3DS Max Archive Import Translation Failure

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm running into some problems with the translation of a 3DS Max archive export.

Following the example from: 
[3ds Max textures/custom materials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245354/3ds-max-textures-custom-materials)

```
$jobInput = array(
  'urn' => $urn,
  'rootFilename' => 'TestFile.max',
  'compressedUrn' => 'True'
);

$jobOutputItem = array(
 'type' => 'svf',
 'views' => array( '2d', '3d' )
);
```

When I translate the standalone TestFile.max it works without any issues (but doesn't pull textures).

When I translate a .zip with only TestFile.max, or with TestFile.max and the textures, the translation fails:

```
{ 
 "urn": "XXX", 
 "type": "manifest", 
 "progress": "complete", 
 "status": "failed", 
 "hasThumbnail": true, 
 "region": "US", 
 "derivatives": [ 
{ 
  "name": "LMV Bubble", 
  "hasThumbnail": true, 
  "outputType": "svf", 
  "progress": "complete", 
  "status": "failed" 
} 
] 
}
```

Any help or ideas would be appreciated!